# Change location with $location.path(path); ng-submit form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i hava form:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="save(myObject)">
...
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="changeLocation('/railway-connection')">Save </button>
</form>
```

As you can see I want to do two things. After submit form it should call the save() function and save the data and it also should change the location.

```
 $scope.save= function (myboject) {
    $scope.saveObj = angular.copy(myboject);

    console.log($scope.saveObj);
};

$scope.changeLocation(path){
    $location.path(path);
};
```

but it does not working. If i click the button it  saves the data and also enters the method changeLocation() but it does not change the location.

if i delete the ng-click and put the **$location.path('/next')** in the function save() (submit-form function) it works.
But I want it in ng-click.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use both ng-submit and ng-click. As it says in the ng-submit documentation :

*Be careful not to cause "double-submission" by using both the ngClick and ngSubmit handlers together.*

Using ng-click call the save function in your controller.

```
<form name="myForm">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save(myobject)">Save</button>
</form>
```

and in your save function change the location path after saving your object.

```
$scope.save= function (myboject) {
   $scope.saveObj = angular.copy(myboject);
   console.log($scope.saveObj);

   $location.path('/next');
};
```